# Python: Scrape videos (that are invisible in HTML) from webpages

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping, python-requests

I would like to download the videos embedded in a set of URL's from the Google Ad Transparency report. Here's a sample page where the video is a YouTube link:

https://transparencyreport.google.com/political-ads/advertiser/AR113835462480625664/creative/CR525481620803682304

And here's a sample page where the video is hosted by google and the video file can be directly downloaded:

https://transparencyreport.google.com/political-ads/advertiser/AR528016269983612928/creative/CR221377870159675392

In both cases, regular browsers (Chrome, Firefox) let me copy the YouTube link URL (top example) or download the linked video file (bottom example).

However, I cannot locate these links in the page source. Can anyone tell me how to locate them, or how one would write a script that would locate the correct tags and grab the video files (or YouTube links)? Is this a dynamic content problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could reach it by the transparencryreport API

For example, the page you attached is getting the video content from the following page:

https://transparencyreport.google.com/transparencyreport/api/v3/politicalads/creatives/details?entity_id=AR528016269983612928&creative_id=CR221377870159675392

Comment: Can I ask how you accessed this or what query you ran to find it? I don't see this info in either:  `bigquery-public-data.google_political_ads.campaign_targeting`
or `bigquery-public-data.google_political_ads.creative_stats`. Getting these links from the API would be way better than scraping them.

Comment: Attila, I did some more digging and still can't find where the website of any of the transparencyreport docs reference this link/query. Can you tell me where you find it? It would be great to query the video links directly from their API.